# mysql merge two queries

Tags: mysql, wordpress, taxonomy

I'm trying to merge these two queries, but I'm not so hot with mysql. I suspect I need to use an `INNER JOIN` or subqueries?

I'm trying to merge a custom taxonomy with a plugin. The plugin requires that I access my Wordpress database with SQL. Here's the query from the plugin:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}most_popular mp
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts p ON mp.post_id = p.ID
WHERE
    p.post_type = '%s' AND
    p.post_status = 'publish'
{$order}
LIMIT %d
```

And this is a query that filters out content by my taxonomy

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts  
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
WHERE 1=1  
    AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (38) ) 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
    AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date 
DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

How should I go about merging all this into one query?

Comment: Once you've marged will you homer?

Comment: @DavidYell I'll take that as a receipt that you read my question :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*, wpt.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms AS wpt1 WHERE wpt1.name='$loc' LIMIT 1) AS wpt
    , {$wpdb->prefix}most_popular AS mp
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships wptr ON (mp.post_id = wptr.object_id) 
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts p ON mp.post_id = p.ID
WHERE 1=1
    AND ( wptr.term_taxonomy_id = wpt.term_id )
    AND p.post_type = '%s'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
{$order}
LIMIT %d
```

It may be ugly, but it works.